# TextWidthBasis.longestLine alternative for AutoSizeText?

Tags: flutter, dart, padding

For a single line of text I have

```
Center(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(
                      width: 1,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: Text('Some text',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 60),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                textWidthBasis: TextWidthBasis.longestLine,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

[image: example]

Which works great. But when I use `AutoSizeText` for multiple lines of text I can't remove the padding with `textWidthBasis: TextWidthBasis.longestLine` so the underline goes fully across the screen.

[image: example]

Is there another way to remove the padding?

Answer (score 0):

I've got two options for you, both of them are workarounds more than solutions to be honest, but sometimes in Flutter, that's the best you've got

(2 is a lot better than 1, good luck! happy coding!)

1.

First is giving the original container a small padding as to not disrupt the text much:

```
 Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border(
                      bottom: BorderSide(
                        width: 1,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: AutoSizeText('Some text\ndummy text\n some texttttttt',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 60),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Which gives this output: https://gyazo.com/0c9d343ba6843d61327f2a33893fc81d

2.

You can wrap the container with a Column and simply but a divider underneath it as so (keep in mind that "indent" and "endIndent" controlles the right/left "padding" of the divider!):

```
Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                child: AutoSizeText(
                  'Some text\ndummy text\n some texttttttt',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              Divider(height: 1, thickness: 1, color: Colors.black, indent: 40, endIndent: 40,)
            ],
          ),
```

Which gives this output: https://gyazo.com/b7cefe2b36442939e13ecf344a858f31

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I don't think a divider will work for my app. I need users to be able to create titles and have the underline be the width of the longest text. Do you know why TextWidthBasis.longestLine isn't an option for AutoSizeText?

Comment: @LeenaMarie I don't unfortunately, sorry :(

Comment: That's alright!